# Regex replacing text unless it's preceeded with backslashes without the usage of look-behind

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have this situation where I am trying to replace a bunch of tags in a block of text using regex, however I also wish to allow the user to escape any tags.

**Note: I want to avoid look ahead / behind since Safari doesn't support it**

Live Example: https://regex101.com/r/mDGs3C/1

```
Welcome {{ PLAYER_NAME }} to the event
```

using a substitution this should render

```
Welcome Richard to the event
```

For this I was using the following regex, which seems to work correctly.

`/{{\s*PLAYER_NAME\s*}}/gm`

However I also want the ability to be able to escape, so the following

```
Welcome {{ PLAYER_NAME }} to the event, you can use tags in here such as \\{{ PLAYER_NAME }}
```

I want to output as ...

```
Welcome Richard to the event, you can use tags in here such as {{ PLAYER_NAME }}
```

So I have tried to use the following at the start of my regular expression to state that I don't want it to match if it contains a double backslash.

```
/[^\\]{{\s*PLAYER_NAME\s*}}/gm
```

This ALMOST works, however it cuts off the last letter of the previous word in some scenarios, take a look at my example to see the e being cut off the word welcome

https://regex101.com/r/mDGs3C/1

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to escape the curlys? ie `[^\\]\{\{\s*PLAYER_NAME\s*}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the non-slashes and put them back in the replacement:

| Operation | Parameter |
| --- | --- |
| Search | `([^\\])\{\{\s*PLAYER_NAME\s*}}` |
| Replace | `$1 Richard` |

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! was just a case of adding it into its own group and than making sure I use that in the replacement :)